# AWS elasticache redis replication groups, cache clusters, cluster mode enabled/disabled configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

There have been some additions to the AWS::Elasticache::ReplicationGroup resource since I last looked at it with Redis 2.8. With Redis 2.8, I enabled a master with a read replica using DNS failover by specifying the `NumCacheClusters` parameter in cloudformation to 2, and setting the `PreferredCacheClusterAZs` so that the replica is not in the same AZ as the master. Now with Redis 3.2 and cluster mode, there is `NumNodeGroups` which is in Redis-speak, a shard, with optional 0-5 replicas per shard. What I am confused about is then what does `NumCacheClusters` do with cluster mode enabled? Is it a legacy option with Redis 2.8? In the docs it does not say that only `NumNodeGroups` or `NumCacheClusters` can be specified at the same time. So what happens if both are say, 2?

Finally, with Redis 2.8 I have always thought `AWS::Elasticache::CacheCluster` is like a "less managed" version of ReplicationGroup where you specify the number of nodes in the cache cluster `NumCacheClusters` but there is no primary, replica relationships between the nodes and it's up to the application to figure out where the data goes. I'm not sure if that assumption is correct. And where does it fit now there is cluster mode with replication groups, but not with `CacheCluster`?

For reference the [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html) page for ReplicationGroups.

Comment: i wish there was an answer to this... aws documentation is appalling

Comment: agreed. banging my head all day. wish this question was answered!

Answer (score 0):

As per [AWS Elasticache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/APIReference/API_CreateReplicationGroup.html) documentation, we can create Redis with either
a) cluster mode disabled, Or
b) cluster mode enabled.
Your question is related to option (b). Please refer to this [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.html#Replication.CreatingReplGroup.NoExistingCluster.Cluster.API). It can be inferred that NumNodeGroups indicates the number of shards and ReplicasPerNodeGroup indicates replica nodes in each node group.